# Can't test my app (unity facebook sdk) in canvas due to https requirement

Tags: facebook, https, xampp, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to test the Facebook Friend Smash canvas example, but I'm running into issues with an https requirement. The "Getting Started" mentions that it is possible to host this through xampp and test through http (localhost). Here's the reference - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas

When I try to set everything up on the developers.facebook.com page, I get an error in the "Apps on Facebook" section. When I enter the Unity Binary URL, it provides the following error - "Must use the HTTPS protocols". Am I missing something in the process or is https the only way? I can post screens from that setup page if it will help to clarify the issue. I'm new to FB development and have never set up a server before this. I appreciate any help.

Here's what I've done so far:
- Created the Web build of Friend Smash using the app ID I acquired on the FB dev page. 
- Installed and ran XAMPP apache server and placed the build file in the "htdocs" folder. 
- I tested the file to make sure it is accessible through http://localhost/[build file name] on my Firefox browser. It loads the file and start screen even though it doesn't appear to be playable. 
- The App shows in "Sandbox mode" when I check the status
- I tried plugging in all the data in the "Apps on Facebook" platform, but it gives the error in the "Unity Binary URL" that I have to use https protocols.

Comment: Why not set up a self-signed SSL cert locally for testing? It should only take a few minutes

Comment: I started working on that yesterday, but I'm running into problems there as well. I downloaded OpenSSL and I've been trying to generate a private key. I went through a few tutorials and it appeared to successfully generate a private key. Then when I went through CMD to use the makecert command, it throws an error that it can't load or locate several files (openssl.cnf, .rnd,privkey.pem, and server.csr). I think there is an issue with the directory it's looking in, and I know some of the files don't exits (maybe I didn't properly generate them).

Comment: Parse might be an easier way to get setup if you don't want to deal with setting up your own https server locally: https://parse.com/

After setting up an app with them, you can look at: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide in how to upload your unity binary.  Once you uploaded the binary in the root of the `public` folder, you can input the url into Facebook as: `https://<your_parse_namespace>.parseapp.com/<your_unity_binary_name>.unity3d`

Comment: I had read about parse, but was looking for a free option first. I see that they have a 30 day trial so I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem.  They also have a basic plan which is free.  It should scale just fine for testing:
https://parse.com/plans

Comment: +1 was about to ask the same thing, would be nice if we could enter an HTTP URL as it says in the docs, while in sandbox mode.  Maybe now that they renamed "sandbox" mode this has been removed/changed, shame if so.  I should have HTTPS soon, but HostGator's online order form isn't working, so this could delay my testing a few days.